Is it safe to grant special permission "s" to traceroute.db?
I have two traceroute programs installed and I've noticed that they don't have the same permissions:
~$ ls -l /usr/bin/inetutils-traceroute 
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 60184 August 23, 2023 /usr/bin/inetutils-traceroute

~$ ls -l /usr/bin/traceroute.db
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 72944 25 feb 2023 /usr/bin/traceroute.db

You can see that traceroute.db doesn't have the special permission "s" and that's why I installed inetutils-traceroute which allows me to use the -I option as a user. But this program comes with a lot of other programs that I don't need at all.
So my question is: can I safely add this special "s" permission to traceroute.db so as to keep only the original package installed by Debian?

are you root? you should be able to set SetUID if you are. its entirely a different question as to whether the app runs properly that way. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid

setting SETUID is not a problem, the question is: if I do it, am I taking a risk? If I only could understand why Debian add a special permission to inetutils-traceroute but not to traceroute?

on its face, yes it should be safe. not sure it will work, but as long as there are no privilege escalation vulnerabilities in the implementation, it should be fine.
